# Error when trying to migrate vue-cli project to typescript

Tags: typescript, vue-cli

I have a vue-cli project that I want to migrate to typescript. Reading [this](https://cli.vuejs.org/core-plugins/typescript.html#parallelization), it states that all I need to do is run the following:

```
vue add typescript
```

***I am running my project on a Windows machine with Git Bash***

This results in the following error:

> Installing vue-cli-plugin-typsecript...
>
> yarn add v1.22.17 [1/4] Resolving packages... info If you think this
> is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in
> info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about
> this command. error An unexpected error occurred:
> "https://registry.npmjs.org/vue-cli-plugin-typsecript: Not found".
> ERROR  command failed: yarn add vue-cli-plugin-typsecript -D --tilde

When looking inside the error log, I see that:

```
> Trace:    Error: https://registry.npmjs.org/vue-cli-plugin-typsecript:
> Not found
>       at Request.params.callback [as _callback] (...\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:67029:18)
>       at Request.self.callback (...\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:140883:22)
>       at Request.emit (events.js:314:20)
>       at Request.<anonymous> (...\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:141855:10)
>       at Request.emit (events.js:314:20)
>       at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (...\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js:141777:12)
>       at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:420:28)
>       at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:326:22)
>       at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1223:12)
>       at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21)
```

I have searched online on how to fix this and stumbled upon [this](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/5865), but every suggested solution there does not work for me.
I have also tried:

- Upgrading yarn
- Removing node modules
- Removing yarn.lock

Nothing seems to work. Any ideas on how I could overcome this issue?

Comment: Are you sure you wrote `vue add typescript`? Because in the error it is misspelled as `typsecript`.

Comment: @lusc - Yes, that seemed to be the error. Thanks!

Comment: @lusc feel free to post it as an answer to benefit from the bounty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @lusc commented, I apparently misspelled typescript and that is why I was receiving the error.

This: ***typsecript*** instead of

this: ***typescript***

Answer (score 0):

Check the spelling

wrongly written "typescript" instead of "typesecript"